# String Value Isn't Updating

Tags: python, string, list

So I've been working on reworking Hangman in Python and I've run into an issue.
The output isn't updating at all. It always remains this mesh of underscores, although other parts of the code, such as the number of tries decreasing or used letters being added to the `used` list seem to function flawlessly.

Here's the code:

```
# IMPORT GUARDS
from random import choice
from os import system
from time import sleep

# DECLARATIONS
wordList = ["apple", "pear"]
gameWord = choice(wordList)

strList = list(gameWord)
strOut = "_" * len(gameWord)

tries = 5
used = []

alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

while True:

    system ("cls")
    print (strOut + "\n")
    print ("Tries Left:", str(tries))
    print ("Letters Used:", used)

    Ltr = input ("Letter: ")

    # INPUT CHECK
    if len(Ltr) != 1 and Ltr.lower() in alphabet:
        print ("Input is of incorect size.")
        sleep(0.5)

    elif len(Ltr) == 0 and Ltr.lower() in alphabet:
        print ("No input value given.")
        sleep(0.5)

    if len(Ltr) == 1 and Ltr.lower() not in alphabet:
        print ("Invalid character input.")
        sleep(0.5)

    if len(Ltr) != 1 and Ltr.lower() not in alphabet:
        print ("Input is both too large and contains invalid characters.")
        sleep(0.5)

    # CORRECT INPUT
    if len(Ltr) == 1 and Ltr.lower() in alphabet:

        ltrPos = ( [pos for pos, char in enumerate(gameWord) if char == Ltr.lower])

        # DECLARATIONS
        Counter = 0
        strcounter = 0

        # CHECKING THE NUM OF TIMES THE INPUT APPEARS IN THE WORD
        while Counter < len(strList):
            if gameWord[Counter].lower() == Ltr.lower():
                strcounter += 1
            Counter += 1

        # INPUT DOES APPEAR
        if strcounter != 0:
            strcounter -= 1
            strOut = list(strOut)

            for i in ltrPos:
                strOut[ltrPos[strcounter]] = Ltr.upper()
                strcounter += 1

            strOut = "".join(strOut)

        # INPUT DOES NOT APPEAR AND/OR IS USED
        elif strcounter == 0:
            if Ltr not in used:
                print ("Letter not in word.")
                used.append(Ltr.lower())
                tries -= 1
            else:
                print ("Letter Already Used.")
                sleep(0.5)

        # OUT OF TRIES
        if tries == 0:
            system("cls")
            print ("Game Over. \nWord: " + gameWord)
            break

        # VICTORY
        if "_" not in strOut:
            system("cls")
            print ("Congratulations!")
            break

system ("pause")
```

All advice is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Typo in your list comprehension `ltrPos = ( [pos for pos, char in enumerate(gameWord) if char == Ltr.lower])`. `lower` should be `lower()`, you are comparing to a function. Voting to close for typo. (Actually, wanted to close for typo, but hit wrong option; still, voting to close...)

Comment: @tobias_k bless you fine sir! But now I'm getting an IndexError('list index out of range',) error message in the `strOut[ltrPos[strcounter]] = Ltr.upper()` section. It happens when I type in a character that is supposed to replace two underscores ie. the `P` in `apple`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you forgot to call the `lower` function in one place:

```
    ltrPos = [pos for pos, char in enumerate(gameWord) if char == Ltr.lower()]
```

But there's more. First, you can simplify the calculation of `strCounter` to

```
    strcounter = len(ltrPos)
```

Or just check `if ltrPos:` instead of `if strcounter != 0:`. Also, you can use `else` instead of `elif`.

The next problem is `strOut[ltrPos[strcounter]]`. Here, you try to access `lrtPos[strcounter]`, which will produce an index error as you decrement `strcounter` just once, instead of setting it back to zero. Instead, just iterate the indices in `ltrPos` directly:

```
        for i in ltrPos:
            strOut[i] = Ltr.upper()
```

Also, note that you only add the letter to the `used` list if it is *not* in the word.